# How to apply styles on editor template model object on mvc app

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

How to apply bootstrapp style on editor template

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressDetails)
```

I tried by adding htmlAttributes like below

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressDetails, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "col-md-4 col-md-4 col-md-4  bounceIn" }, })
```

`model.AddressDetails` have multiple properties which i need to display in 3 columns in multiple rows.

```
public class AddressDetails
{
    [Required]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine5 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine6 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

But the result came like first row is having 3 columns and the next row it is scattered here and there. The alignment is wrong.

I think the way i have coded is wrong. I am using Bootstrapp v3.1.1

Comment: You have tagged this MVC-4, but adding html attributes in `EditorFor()` is only supported in MVC-5.1 or higher

Comment: I might be wrong with the way i applied html attributes.In MVC 4 how can i apply html attribute?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressDetails, new { @class = "col-md-4 col-md-4 col-md-4  bounceIn" })`

Comment: I tried this , but the width applied only to the first 3 properties in the model. After that the allignment is wrong . The fifth property addressline5 is not coming right under the 2nd column. I mean the textbox control is not fitting into the second column

Comment: What 5 properties? - all the code you have shown is for one element.

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant code (not in comments)

Comment: And you need to create a custom `EditorTemplate` that include the html attributes, or create individual inputs in the view for each property with their attributes.

Comment: If you dont mind can you show me an example to create custom editor template . I am a beginner in mvc

Comment: Just create `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine1, new { ..... })` etc for each property in the model

Comment: So you mean with Editortemplate(model) it wont work?

Comment: Only if you have a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `AddressDetails` that includes `@Html.TextBoxFor()` for each property and add the html attributes

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I have created custom template and made it work.Great help. I could progress now.Now only one issue is pending with datepicker.The calendar icon is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In EditorTemplate file you can get htmlAttributes and use from like following:

```
@model string

@{
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, htmlAttributes)
```